# Computer freezes when more memory is malloced

Tags: c, ubuntu, memory

I am trying to run a C program which mallocs the memory as per the input given by user.

Whenever I input something as big as 1000000000 rather than returning NULL value, my Ubuntu 14.04 machine freezes completely! I am damn sure that malloc is the culprit...

But I am surprised to see Ubuntu freeze!

Does anyone have any idea about why this may be happening?

I have a laptop with 12GB RAM, i5 processor and 500GB harddisk. and Ubutnu 14.04 OS

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define LEFT(x) (2*(x)+1)
#define RIGHT(x) (2*(x)+2)

long long int *err, *sorted, *size, *id;
short int *repeat;

void max_heapify(long long int *arr, long long int length, long long int index)
{
  long long int largest, left, right, temp, flag = 1;

  while (flag)
    {
      left = LEFT(index);
      right = RIGHT(index);

      if (left < length && arr[left] > arr[index])
    largest = left;
      else
    largest = index;

      if (right < length && arr[right] > arr[largest])
    largest = right;

      if (largest != index)
    {
      temp = arr[index];
      arr[index] = arr[largest];
      arr[largest] = temp;
      index = largest;
    }
      else
    flag = 0;
    }
}

void build_max_heap(long long int *arr, long long int length)
{
  long long int i, j;
  j = (length / 2) - 1;
  for (i = j; i >= 0; i--)
    max_heapify(arr, length, i);
}

void heapsort(long long int *arr, long long int length)
{
  long long int i, temp, templength;

  build_max_heap(arr, length);

  templength = length;
  for (i = 0; i < templength; i++)
    {
      temp = arr[0]; // maximum number
      arr[0] = arr[length - 1];
      arr[length - 1] = temp;
      length--;
      max_heapify(arr, length, 0);
    }
}

int main()
{
  long long int n, k, p, i, j;
  scanf("%lld%lld%lld",&n, &k, &p);
  err = (long long int*)malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(long long int));
  //repeat = (short int*)calloc(1000000001 , sizeof(short int));
  sorted = (long long int*)malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(long long int));
  j = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      scanf("%lld",&err[i]);
      sorted[j++] = err[i];
    }

  heapsort(sorted, j);

  for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
    printf("%lld, ",sorted[i]);

  //These malloc statements cause the problem!! 
  id = (long long int*)malloc((sorted[j - 1] + 1) * sizeof(long long int));
  size = (long long int*)malloc((sorted[j - 1] + 1) * sizeof(long long int));

  for(i = 0; i <= sorted[j - 1]; i++)
    {
      id[i] = i;
      size[i] = 1;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Basically I am trying to sort the numbers and then allocate the array of size of maximum element. This program works for smaller input but when I enter this

```
5 5 5 

1000000000 999999999 999999997 999999995 999999994
```

It freezes ubuntu ..I even added the condition to check if id or size is NULL but that didn't help! If system is unable to allocate that much memory then it should return NULL but system freezes! And this code works fine on MAC!

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "freeze"? Can you still move the mouse cursor? Can you shrink down your code to basically a main function with the two malloc calls using hard coded parameters and see if it still freezes? If its really the `mallocs` which cause the issue all the heap sort related code is not necessary for reproduction

Comment: I am unable to do anything! I can't move mouse, I can't open terminal I have no option but to hard reset! Yup I reduced the code but that code worked!

Comment: So, where is your **shortest** reproduction case. (and in case you didn't know it, `1000000000 * sizeof(long long)` is over 7.62 **gigabytes** of allocation, and you're doing it at least *twice*. It may take *considerable* time to swap that in/out of paging storage). If what you say is true, about 95% of this code is unneeded to reproduce your issue, so start cutting.

Comment: @WhozCraig If system is unable to allocate that much memory then it should return NULL why freeze? Or is it because 12GB RAM (cause my MAC has only 4GB RAM and there it returned NULL!)

Comment: @harrythomas I submit to you it *can* allocate that much memory (**not** "RAM"), and see no evidence to the contrary. If this is a 64-bit compilation. this *can* work, but will be terribly inefficient. If it is a 32bit compilation you could be facing an overflow on the size calculation, and the process could/should puke.

Comment: Got it! But I am still confused about how can MAC run the program easily!

Comment: Does your MAC have an SSD? (mine does, an MB-air). That `calloc` would be terribly expensive btw, as *all* of that allocation would have to be swapped in to physical RAM, one or more pages at a time, just to zero-initialize the content, then swapped back out to page storage. Yuck. You should update your question with your toolchain version *and* target platform bit width (32bit vs 64bit) btw.

Comment: And btw, if you do target this for 32bit you *better* receive a warning from your compiler to the effect of : "Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'unsigned long'". This is regarding converting a `long long` to a `size_t` on typical 32bit platforms. 7.62 gB storage cannot happen on such a target, and *should* return NULL as you claim, followed by your process crashing due to UB (eventually).

Comment: Mine is 64 bit ubuntu..but Anyway thanks for the explanation!